# LateInitializationError: Field '_image@785213298' has not been initialized. in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am working with flutter project and uploading a image file to mysql server but on the screen i get this error:

> LateInitializationError: Field '_image@785213298' has not been initialized.

and this is the code which i am using:

```
late File _image;

Future choiceImage() async{

final picker=ImagePicker();

var pickedImage= await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  _image=File(pickedImage!.path);
});
   }

Future choice2Image() async{

final picker=ImagePicker();

var pickedImage= await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
setState(() {
  _image=File(pickedImage!.path);
});
}

Future uploadImage() async{
final uri=Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/driverapp-apis");
var request =http.MultipartRequest('POST',uri);
request.fields['id']=widget.id.toString();
request.fields['licence']=licenseController.text;
request.fields['expiry']=expiryController.text;
request.fields['action']="updateDocs";
var pic =await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("image", _image.path);
request.files.add(pic);
var response=await request.send();

if (response.statusCode==200){
  print("image uploaded");
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => aadharCardScreen(widget.id),
    ),
  );
}
else{
  print("image not uploaded");
}
}
```

and also selcting file with buttons:

```
onPressed: () {
                  choice2Image();
                },
```

and

```
 onPressed: () {
                  choiceImage();
                },`
```

and also showing the selected image in container:

```
Container(
            child: Image.file(
              _image,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
```

i know that is late initialization which states that variable i never initialized but it gets its value after choosing photo or taking photos, what i am doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have solved the past question, then it's the same as that do not use late initialization and use null ```?``` safety.

Comment: The error says, the late variable is not initialized! and you're trying to access it. If you use `late` you must intialize it before accessing it. the better idea is use nullable `File? image` then handle for null case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

> late File _image;

set

> File? _image;

```
Container(
   child: _image != null? Image.file(
        _image,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ) : const SizedBox(),
         ),
```

and uploadImage() if _image != null

Answer (score 0):

rather then using late you can use null(?) operator to handle that image case because late function required to initialize value so you can use (?) in file selection.